# What could be causing 'error processing argument' using webcontents.executeJavaScript?

Tags: electron

After I create a new BrowserWindow I launch this code on its webContents

```
newRoom.webContents.executeJavaScript(
        client.emit("authentication", {
          username: "bob",
          password: "1234"
        })
      );
```

The code executes fine but I'm getting an error thrown in devtools -

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Error processing argument at index 1, conversion failure from #<Object>
```

Is there something wrong perhaps with the formatting of the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, reading the documentation is probably the first and best thing to do...

The webContents method [contents.executeJavaScript](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture) is expecting a *string* of code as first argument...

This could do the trick:

```
newRoom.webContents.executeJavaScript(
        'client.emit("authentication", { username: "bob", password: "1234" })'
      );
```

or:

```
newRoom.webContents.executeJavaScript(
        `client.emit("authentication", {
          username: "bob",
          password: "1234"
        })`
      );
```

However, the original question mentions that "the code executes fine", which would mean that it doesn't even need to be passed to the renderer process to get executed...

```
client.emit("authentication", {
              username: "bob",
              password: "1234"
            });
```

Comment: I did notice that the javascript was escaped with parentheses in docs.  However searching around for whatever examples I could find - some examples had them, others did not.  Adding them though gives me a new error.  I'll have to did some more but I'm going to close this out and move on for now.  Thank you!